# How pass reference to "this" on href javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I have a link with this href:

```
href="javascript:foo(this);"
```

when I call it "this" points to the window object, not the link. How do I pass a reference to the link?

http://jsfiddle.net/xMGKz/

**Edit note**: The question is how to pass with href, not generally - I know about onclick!

And not copying id and make getElementById, that's not "this", it's DOM search for certain element, no need to make it inline in HTML.

The anwer is: not possible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use "javascript: .... " in an href, you are calling this function globaly. Not in the context of the link.
You can try with:

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo(this); return false;">MyLink</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xMGKz/1/

Comment: on this call, `this` will refer to the `a` element regardless. although, this method of event binding is not recommended, you better tie it to the anchor object representation, not the DOM element.

Comment: @Eliran Malka: Thats what lxx was asking for... to pass the A element by reference.

Comment: I know it works with onclick, was just wondering why it doesn't work with href. There's no way then to get reference to this with href, if it's called globally.

Comment: This is because, the "command" `javascript:` executes the code with no context at all. It's the same as writing in the browsers address bar. If you want to get the context of the element, you have to use javascript events (like onclick, onXXX, etc)

Comment: try this: `<a href="javascript:alert(this === window)">my link</a>` it should say "true"...  think of "javascript:" the same way you would think of eval() or just plain loading a new javascript file, it executes inside of the global context.. hope this helps -ck

Comment: `href="#"` makes page scroll to the top

Comment: @basin You're right, I corrected the code to prevent this. If you "return false" it won't happen.

Answer (score 4):

subjectively you would be better suited with something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="myAnchor">My Link</a>
```

and then to code:

```
document.getElementById('myAnchor').onclick = function() {
    // this is the <a> in here
    return false; // optional, prevents href from executing at all 
};
```

this way everything is a little more clear. hope this helps -ck

Answer (score 4):

Better to;

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(this.href);">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add an ID field to your anchor.

Then...

Using standard Javascript:

```
<a id="someLink" href="javascript:foo(document.getElementById('someLink'));">
```

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<a id="someLink" href="javascript:foo($('#someLink'));">
```

Comment: But this makes me to insert the id 2 times for each link in the text and that's something I want to avoid.