# How to find Id of <tr> element from inside <a> element?

Tags: jquery

i have html like this, i want to get `<tr id="Box<%# Eval("Id") %>"`when i click on 5  tag , using jquery

please note this is my `ItemTemplate`, so there are many items with same html,

```
<tr id="Box<%# Eval("Id") %>" style="height: 30px;">
        <td>
            <div class="LanguageName"><%# Eval("LanguageName")%></div>
        </td>
        <td text-align: center;">
            <a href="javascript:fun1(1)"></a>
            <a href="javascript:fun1(2)"></a>
            <a href="javascript:fun1(3)"></a>
            <a href="javascript:fun1(4)"></a>
            <a href="javascript:fun1(5)"></a>
        </td>
```

please have a look here for 2 items : http://jsfiddle.net/bThbL/

so when i click on any `<a>` from td , i wan to get parent `tr` id

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/3LAyt/1/)**

```
idofTr = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Comment: Check the live demo I made for you.

Comment: The demo you given has jquery Motorolas 1.4.5, please change it to jquery 1.8.2

Comment: @ i am not using Motorolas 1.4.5,! i put online jquery link in header

Comment: Can you use onclick instead of href as href could not pass the object as far as I know

Comment: Please have a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702040/how-pass-reference-to-this-on-href-javascript-function

Answer (score 0):

Can use this

```
$(this).closest('tr')[0].id  // DOM Object
```

**OR** Use `.closest()`

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');  // jQuery Object
```

Comment: You have set the framework to moo tools .. Change it to jQuery .. Also $(this) has no context as you are not passing the this object .. this will be the window object according too your function

Comment: Pass it this way href="javascript:SetRead(1,this)"  And the function function SetRead(val, elem) {
            alert($(elem).closest('tr').attr('id'));
        }

Comment: It's a bad practice to use inline scripts and styles.. Separate them into files.. Also why do want to add the function to each link.. You can get it done by single event handler.. I have used HTML-5 data-attribute to store the value .. Check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bThbL/9/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a onclick="fun1.call(this,1)"></a>
```

Script:

```
function fun1(val){
   var trId = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
}
```

BTW don't use JQuery if not needed to avoid resource wasting.

Comment: It works: use "onclick" instead of "href" to avoid losing "this" reference. Then you can use my method or anyone else's method to get the id. On ur jsfiddle, you can find it working on first "1" button.